# Swift convert NSError to String

Tags: swift

Is there a way to convert an error of type NSError in swift to a string?

For example for something like this:

```
do {
    try response.status(.OK).send(fileName: "html/index.html")
} catch {
    response.status(.FAIL).send(error.CONVERT_TO_STRING)
}
```

.send() expects a string by default.

Comment: Do you mean catching the Error that was thrown (in Swift) or the http error?

Comment: I clarified my question.

Comment: No you didn't. What sort of thing _is_ the error? An enum? An NSError? Don't make us guess.

Comment: I thought every error in swift inherits from a base error class?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If your error is of type `NSError`, you can use `error.localizedDescription` to get the string.

Comment: That's true, however the error in a Swift `catch` block may not be an `NSError`. It's not clear in this case whether it is.

Comment: My assumption was that every error in swift needs to implement the ErrorType protocol. Is there a way to convert an object of this type to a string.

Comment: Not directly, you would have to know more about the error to convert it to a string. Casting to an NSError if it's some enum that implements the ErrorType protocol would be pretty useless.

Comment: @TomHarrington Swift 5 can not catch `NSException` nor `fatal_error`. We would get compile error if it was not guaranteed to be of correct type (with message like: object has no `localizedDescription` property). This is advantage to JS or PHP.

Comment: I don't know what JS or PHP has to do with this.

Answer (score 21):

`error.localizedDescription` doesn't always contain all the information you need.  In that instance you do have the option of converting the whole object to a string...

`let description = "\(error)"`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Its an all case solution.